# How to prove that a function is irrational?

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to know how to prove that a given function is irrational. Examples:
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}
$$
$$
f(x)=\tan(x) 
$$
Information about the definition of rational and irrational functions would be also helpful.

Comment: In general a rational function is defined by the quotient of polynomials, i.e. $r$ is a rationial function iff r=p/q where p,q are polynomials and q is not vanishing somewhere.

Comment: Hint: rational function maps rationals to rationals.

Comment: @Wojowu $\pi x$ is a rational function.

Comment: I don't think "irrational function" is standard nomenclature.

Comment: @GFauxPas But was used in the past. It is how old Calculus books used to call functions with radicals.

Comment: @Pp.. sorry, I thought the polynomials have to have rational coefficients too. I think it's an understandable mistake :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rational functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) are functions that are equal to a quotient of polynomials.

As a consequence they have only finitely many zeros (finitely many poles, their derivatives are rational, and many other properties). This implies, that the example $\tan(x)$ can't be rational because it has infinitely many zeros.

You can prove that $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is not rational by imitating the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number.

> Assume there are polynomials $p(x),q(x)$ with greatest common divisor $1$, such that >! $$\sqrt{1+x^2}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$
>  Then $$(1+x^2)q(x)^2=p(x)^2$$
>  Therefore $1+x^2$ divides $p(x)^2$. Since $1+x^2=(i-x)(-i-x)$ is square free, then $1+x^2$ divides $p(x)$, i.e. $p(x)=(1+x^2)r(r)$. Therefore 
> $$(1+x^2)q(x)=(1+x^2)^2r(x)^2$$
> It follows that $$q(x)=(1+x^2)r(x)^2$$
> This means that $1+x^2$ should divide also $q(x)$. But this contradicts that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have greatest common divisor $1$.

If we were working with numbers such that $1+1=0$ then $$1+x^2=(1+x)^2$$ Therefore $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sqrt{(1+x^2)^2}=1+x$ would be rational.

Comment: More simply, set x=1.

Comment: @martycohen $x\sqrt{2}$ is a polynomial. Rational functions over $\Bbb R$ are usually/often allowed to have arbitrary real coefficients.

Comment: Oh. I was thinking that  the polynomials had to have integer coefficients.